# Non-Linear Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

EHA enterprises has been manufacturing $500$ dishwashers a day $\delta$ selling them for $\$400$ each. There has been very little profit, however, and an outside consultant is called into study this operation. He finds that the cost function is $C(q)= q^2 - 440q + 165000$, provided at least $250$ dishwashers are made daily

Find the profit
Find the maximum profit (do not use calculus)
What advice does he gives them?
The market changes so that the selling price for a dishwasher is $\$360$. What should EHA enterprises do now?

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profit $P(q)$ is the income minus the cost, so

$$P(q)=400q - (q^2 - 440q + 165000)= 840q - q^2 - 165000$$

provided $q \ge 250$ again.

The top of a parabola ($aq^2+bq+c$) is (standard knowledge) at $\frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{-840}{-2}=420$ ( a maximum because of the negative $a$; in the right $q$-domain, so OK). So they should make fewer dishwashers.

With a new price we get a new $P(q)$. Try that with the same approach.